# euler question about strings and ints

Tags: string

i am currently programming in euler (mathematics)
the problem is i need to split the first 10 numbers and the latst 2

: 012345678912 =

0123456789      12

i can do this by using the substring method
but i need to calculate further with the first 10 numbers
so what i can do is cast the string back to an int 
but i have no idea how to do it ..
can anyone help me ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

An easier way is to get the last 2 digits using the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

```
012345678912 % 100 = 12
```

And then getting the rest by doing [integer division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_division#Division_of_integers) by 100:

```
012345678912 // 100 = 123456789
```

The exact syntax needed varies depending on the language.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your programming language.

In C#, it would be the following: `int.Parse(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2));`

However, I would do it mathematically as Sebastian P. detailed.

Comment: indeed i used ceil ((number/100) - 1)
so the number it returned was all before the last 2 numbers..
worked thanks alot !